# Number of 1 time,2 times, 3 times, n times column entries in table in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Have Table :

```
id    userid    type    created_date
1    4353535    1    04-06-2014
2    4353536    0    06-06-2014
3    4353537    1    11-06-2014
4    4353538    1    11-06-2014
5    4353539    0    19-06-2014
7    4353541    1    01-06-2014
10    4353544    1    12-06-2014
11    4353535    1    06-06-2014
12    4353536    1    10-06-2014
13    4353537    1    12-06-2014
```

What I Want : (with in date range)

> How much user have single time entry with type 1
>   How much user have double time entry with type 1
>   How much user have triple time entry with type 1
>   How much user have four time entry with type 1
>   How much user have n time entry with type 1

(PHP & MYSQL)

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: `select userid, count(id) from tablename group by userid`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol OP wasn't asking for a query. Or atleast he didn't mention

Comment: exactly i want that how many user have single entry , how many users have 2 times entry and so on...who have type =1

Comment: @Daan MySQL tag, table structure... looks like a query query to me ;)

Comment: explaining - like userid 4353535 and 4353537 have 2 times entry in type 1 out put will be 2 users have 2 times entry in type 1 . and other 4 userid have 1 times entry in type 1

Answer (score 0):

First get the count for each user, then from that group the entrycount you can get your expected output

```
select EntryCount, count(userid) from (Select userid, count(id) as Entrycount from myentry group by userid where type=1) as sq group by Entrycount
```

This will work try

Answer (score 0):

First, get the number of entries per user.  Then, get the number of users grouped by number of entries.

```
SELECT numEntries, COUNT(*) AS numUsers
FROM (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS numEntries
    FROM tablename
    WHERE type = 1
    GROUP BY userid
) tbl
GROUP BY numEntries
```

[Simplified demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/191ea/1)

[Demo with your data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e985d/1)